# Creating control from 'control array?'

Tags: vb.net, control-array

I have an array of picture boxes as so:

```
    Dim pieces(500) As PictureBox
    pieces(1) = New PictureBox
    With pieces(1)
        .CreateControl()
        .Visible = True
        .BackColor = Color.Red
        .Width = 50
        .Height = 50
        .Left = 50
        .Top = 50
    End With
```

The program does not crash or anything, but the picturebox is no where to be seen on the form. How to I make this work correctly?

And is 'Control Array' the correct term for this? or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't show up until you add those PictureBoxes to a form.

I suppose you already have a Windows Form, so all you have to do is:
`Window.Controls.Add(PictureBox)`

Supposing your form object is called "Window"

You need to add them one by one and they don't need to be on an array, that's why there's a Control collection inside the Windows Form

Control Array is a VB 6 term, is not used in .NET anymore. The programming model between .NET and VB 6 is **very** different, you should take the time to go through a good tutorial or good book.

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks. As for the term 'Array of Controls' I think what I meant was an 'Array of Objects'. TYVM.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add it to the form or panel where you want it/them displayed.

[CreateControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.createcontrol.aspx) only creates children and forces the creation of the control's Handle, but it will not place it onto the a form or parent control (it wouldn't know what to add it too!).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I remember trying this a while ago and it didn't work for creating an object. Slipped my mind I guess.

Comment: It happens to everyone. Good luck :)