# Automatically create WebBrowser controls in VB.net/2010

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I started to code a program in VB6 only because I knew the language well and how to work with it. I unfortunately ran into some snags since it's an older program, and now I'm learning the more recent version of it (2010) but have a question:

How do I create more instances of WebBrowser in this latest version? This is my code from VB6 to help you get an idea of what I mean:

```
If Not AdBrowser(URLs.ListIndex + 1) Then
    'For i = 1 To URLs.ListCount - 1
    Load AdBrowser(URLs.ListIndex + 1)
    'Next i
    AdBrowser(URLs.ListIndex + 1).Left = 120
    AdBrowser(URLs.ListIndex + 1).Top = 240
    AdBrowser(URLs.ListIndex + 1).Height = 7695
    AdBrowser(URLs.ListIndex + 1).Width = 15975
End If
```

Basically what the code is doing is when someone clicks on the list box, it creates a new instance of AdBrowser and keeps the Array # the same index as the list index. I need similar code that will do the same thing in the latest VB..

I know you can't do the same thing as before and I've looked it up on Google with a couple different variations and still nothing.  I've found stuff related to creating control arrays which is basically what I'm doing here, but nothing that would work with WebBrowser control.

### New question!

Now I'm having troubles finding a way to check if the browser is already loaded, this is my code that isn't working but has the right idea:

```
For i = 0 To BrowserArray.Count
        BrowserArray(i).Visible = False
    Next
    If Not BrowserArray(URLs.SelectedIndex) Then

    Else
        BrowserArray = New AdBrowserArray(Me)
        BrowserArray.AddNewBrowser(MainFrame)
        BrowserArray(URLs.SelectedIndex).Navigate("http://google.com")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Controls can be used in an array just like any other object.

Have a look at the following SO questions regarding control arrays in VB.NET:

[Control Arrays in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497403/control-array-in-vb-net)

[Creating control from 'control array?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925693/creating-control-from-control-array)

You should be able to use the webbrowser just like any other control so maybe post some .NET code so we can have a look whats wrong

Comment: Ok so I did find some working code on Microsoft's dev website, but now i'm running into a problem where i'm not sure how to check if the control already exists and not to load a new one if it doesn't have to. i will paste the code above so you can see it better.